# How can we set repository for lambda function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

Can i make my lambda function to automatically store in some repository every time i press save button something like commit but directly from aws lambda code editor?

Comment: Maybe AWS Cloud9 (https://aws.amazon.com/cloud9/) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks i think you are right this might do the job (Y)

Answer (score 0):

The Lambda Editor doesn't have a notion of code versioning like git does - it basically takes the zip file you give to Lambda that contains your code, extracts it and lets you edit that. If you press save it creates a new zip and configures the Runtime Environment to use the new code.

Linking that to any Repo like git is to the best of my knowledge **not directly possible**.

I usually use the Online Editor only for debugging, because running my unit tests etc. doesn't really work there as well.